# Python / Pandas convert object with date and time into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have 2 x columns called Start_Time and End_time, they each contain dates in this format: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm".

I am trying to extract/ clean up the info so that Start/ End Time show time only, and that new columns Start_Date and End_Date show date only.

I have seen 101 examples of this online and by all accounts the following *should* work:

```
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time']).dt.date
df['Start_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time']).dt.time
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Time']).dt.date
df['End_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Time']).dt.time
```

I am getting the following error however:

"TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime"

Start_Time and End_time are currently objects - I have tried converting them to to type datetime but also run into errors.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for avoid overwrite original column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start_Time':['02/03/2022 15:15','05/03/2022 15:15'],
                   'End_Time':['12/03/2022 20:15','07/04/2022 20:15']})

df = df.assign(Start_Date = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'], dayfirst=True).dt.date,
                   Start_Time = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'], dayfirst=True).dt.time,
                   End_Date = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Time'], dayfirst=True).dt.date,
                   End_Time = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Time'], dayfirst=True).dt.time )

print (df)
  Start_Time  End_Time  Start_Date    End_Date
0   15:15:00  20:15:00  2022-03-02  2022-03-12
1   15:15:00  20:15:00  2022-03-05  2022-04-07
```

Or use helper variables:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start_Time':['02/03/2022 15:15','05/03/2022 15:15'],
                   'End_Time':['12/03/2022 20:15','07/04/2022 20:15']})

s1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'], dayfirst=True)
s2 = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Time'], dayfirst=True)

df['Start_Date'] = s1.dt.date
df['End_Date'] = s2.dt.date
df['Start_Time'] = s1.dt.time
df['End_Time'] = s2.dt.time

print (df)
  Start_Time  End_Time  Start_Date    End_Date
0   15:15:00  20:15:00  2022-03-02  2022-03-12
1   15:15:00  20:15:00  2022-03-05  2022-04-07
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

First solution I am getting error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" - It doesn't seem to like ".assign(Start_Date". 

Helper variables also unfortunately return: "TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime"

Comment: @afroduck - Can you try `s1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'].astype(str))
s2 = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Time'].astype(str))` ?

Comment: Hey thanks for your help on this... I worked out the issue - I was trying to do this on sliced data - Once I turned the sliced data into a proper dataframe it worked. Cheers!